CSS: create the optical illusion of a column layout using rows
I have a layout that consists of rows that contain columns (they are all divs). I want to create the illusion of a column based table, even though I am using rows.
I want each column in a row to match the corresponding column in another row’s width. So for example, column 2 in row 1 is 300px, therefore column 2 in row 2 is also 300px. But column 1 or 3 could be other widths (but equal to their corresponding column).
The tricky part is that the columns can be different widths depending on content in them, so I can just give them specific widths to start.

Is this possible with CSS grid of flex box? Or does the fact these columns are in separate rows make it impossible without javascript?
EDIT: clarification

Is the data tabular? If it is, use a <table> element (that's what they're for). If this is purely for layout, then yes: of course there are ways (barring any particularly finicky potential needs).

Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I managed to solve this by using 'display: contents' on the parent rows, which treats the children of each row as children of the row's parents. This allowed me to then assign a grid column to each element in a single grid view.

CSS Tables can do that.


.grid {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.item {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
}

.wide {
  width: 300px;
}

.slim {
  width: 50px;
}
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item wide"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item slim"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>



